# How to create an ID column based on condition of previous row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to group hospital admission transfers, with the initial index admission. So far I have been able to categorize each admission as 'index' or 'transfer' based on the time since previous discharge. Now I am trying to group together the admissions together that are in the same episode of care (e.g. each index admission and its associated transfers).

I have tried creating an `episode_id` field to group transfers with the appropriate index admission. I am trying to set `episode_id` to sort by `uli` (individual identifier) and `admitdate_dt` (admission date), and then run through each row. I want to have `episode_id` = previous `episode_id` if `admission_type` is transfer. If `admission_type` is index, I want `episode_id` to be equal to previous `episode_id`+ 1.
The problem with the code below (I think) is it is not looping through each row individually, but running all rows at once with current value of `NULL` for all rows except the first, which I manually set. How can I write the code to loop through each row sequentially and get the desired output below?

```
ALTER TABLE dad_index_admissions_2
ADD episode_id INT; -- Creating an episode id field
    
UPDATE admissions
SET episode_id = 1
WHERE seqnum = (SELECT seqnum FROM admissions ORDER BY uli, admitdate_dt FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);
-- Setting the first row with an episode_id of 1. Seqnum is primary key for admissions table. ULI is individual identifier.

SELECT CASE WHEN episode_id = 1 THEN 1 WHEN admission_type = 'transfer' THEN (LAG(episode_id) OVER(PARTITION BY uli ORDER BY uli, admitdate_dt))
WHEN admission_type = 'index' THEN ((LAG(episode_id+1) OVER(ORDER BY uli, admitdate_dt)))
END AS episode_id, admitdate_dt, disdate_dt, uli, admission_type
FROM admissions; -- My attempt to generate values for episode_id.
```

Example Of Desired Output:

| episode_id | admitdate_dt | disdate_dt | uli | admission_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 - JAN - 2022 | 02- JAN - 2022 | 001 | index |
| 1 | 02 - JAN - 2022 | 10- JAN - 2022 | 001 | transfer |
| 1 | 10 - JAN - 2022 | 20- JAN - 2022 | 001 | transfer |
| 2 | 01 - JAN - 2022 | 05- JAN - 2022 | 002 | index |
| 3 | 10 - JAN - 2022 | 20- JAN - 2022 | 002 | index |
| 3 | 20 - JAN - 2022 | 25- JAN - 2022 | 002 | transfer |

Comment: You want the code to "get the desired output below?" from what data ?

Comment: The data  that I have looks just like the table in the question, except without the episode_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the number of `index` rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE admission_type WHEN 'index' THEN 1 END)
         OVER (ORDER BY uli, admitdate_dt)
         AS episode_id,
       admitdate_dt,
       disdate_dt,
       uli,
       admission_type
FROM   admissions;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE admissions (admitdate_dt, disdate_dt, uli, admission_type) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-02', '001', 'index' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-02', DATE '2022-01-10', '001', 'transfer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-10', DATE '2022-01-20', '001', 'transfer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-05', '002', 'index' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-10', DATE '2022-01-20', '002', 'index' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-20', DATE '2022-01-25', '002', 'transfer' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EPISODE_ID | ADMITDATE_DT | DISDATE_DT | ULI | ADMISSION_TYPE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 01-JAN-22 | 02-JAN-22 | 001 | index |
> | 1 | 02-JAN-22 | 10-JAN-22 | 001 | transfer |
> | 1 | 10-JAN-22 | 20-JAN-22 | 001 | transfer |
> | 2 | 01-JAN-22 | 05-JAN-22 | 002 | index |
> | 3 | 10-JAN-22 | 20-JAN-22 | 002 | index |
> | 3 | 20-JAN-22 | 25-JAN-22 | 002 | transfer |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=549ee1714987fc1765b71e8a90a95fe7)*